# Can not import package created in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import, importerror

I have created 2 python packages in pycharm (Windows) (init.py-s are empty),

[image]

and imported a file from the second package to the first one (*one.p*y):

```
from bgr import two
```

That's all, nothing else, no circular imports.
When I run the file form the command line:

```
python one.py
```

I get an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bgr'
```

What's interesting, it works normally when I run from the pycharm UI. What can cause such a strange behavior.

Comment: go up a directory level and try `python asd\one.py` - does that work?

Comment: When running from the command line what's your cwd? (Current working directory, where you run the command)

Comment: @barny No, it does not.

Comment: @tituszban I have tried several ones, project root and even OS root. Everywhere the same problem exists. Also I've tried with and without virtual env.

Comment: Try `export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd):$PYTHONPATH` from your project directory before running the python script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your working directory is inside `asd`, then it expects a module called `bgr` **inside** `asd`. In pycharm your working directory is `test_me` which is outside `asd` and that's why it works.

Just go to the `test_me` directory and type:

```
python asd/one.py
```

It should work

Another option is to add `bgr` to the `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable. Then `bgr` can be imported from anywhere.

---

Edit:

You could also use [relative imports](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/).

```py
from ..bgr import two
```

This however in order to run **requires** that you are inside `asd` (it won't work from `test_me`). The modules are searched from where you are running the script not from where the script importing them is.

There is a workaround to make it work for both locations:

```py
try:
    from bgr import two
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    from ..bgr import two
```

This only works for these two locations though (inside `test_me` and inside `test_me/asd`). It won't work for any other locations.

There are a couple of workarounds to make it work for **any location** such as changing your cwd while inside the stript (e.g. with `os.chdir()`) or by changing the `PYTHONPATH` while inside the script (e.g. `sys.path.append()`), but they **aren't recommended** because they will only work for your computer and only if you don't change their location.

Comment: `Just go to the test_me directory and type`: doesn't help. Don't like PYTHONPATH approach, as I don't want  bgr to be visible everywhere.

Comment: @Serob_b I added a few more options you can try. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll try. But why everythig is so complicated? I think package/module importing is one of the key features of the language and shuold be orginized in a clear and simple manner. I am coming from Java, and never havd an issue like this.

Comment: It's a different philosophy than java. Instead of having each program compiled along with all its dependencies python uses the logic of system-wide libraries (or at least environment-wide). The pros are obvious. The con of this is that if you make 10 projects you'll have the same libraries compiled 10 times. Another problem with this that you should be aware of is with library versioning (scripts might stop to work after updates). While java aims at system and platform independence, python aims at minimalism on this regard. It's a different philosophy...

Comment: `from ..bgr import two` gives  `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package` (both from test_me and inside asd).

Comment: You could then try some of the workarounds I mentioned. E.g. `import os; os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))` to change the directory to `asd` from wherever you are and then if you want a regular import you can just: `os.chdir('..')` to go back to `test_me`.

Comment: Eventually I solved the problem by with `ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
sys.path.append(ROOT_DIR)`. Adding this lines once (on file(s) which will be called first) will make the script to be runnable from anywhere, independent form the working directory location.

Answer (score 1):

Follow your comments above, I've see that you want to work on `asd` folder. Don't want your `bgr` to be visible everywhere. So I bet that `PYTHONPATH` is not an option that you looking for. Here is something you can try:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "../")
from bgr import two
```

This will add `bgr` module and allow you to use it like your current expectation.
More details here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/470982/how-to-add-a-python-module-to-syspath

Comment: Is that a normal case? I just want to have a project containing different packages (like django standard project) and have possibility to import them one into another? I don't want to use PYTHONPATH (which sys.path.insert does).It sounds like an absurd to add a path into global, when I don;t need it anywhere else.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but if you want to do like Django standard project then you should use PYTHONPATH, like they do. We can't see it but when we call ./manage.py then this function `execute_from_command_line` will add current directory into PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Anyway, `sys.path.insert(0, "../")` worked when I am in inside 'asd'. What if I am in a root directory, what parameter(s) should I pass to insert() method to be workable from anywhere I call 'asd/one.py'?

Comment: you could use absolute path also, like so: `sys.path.insert(0, "/home/username/code/bgr")``

Comment: Eventually I used wider solution, just added not hard-coded absolute path, but using __ file __ variable:
`ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
sys.path.append(ROOT_DIR)`