# Example of creating and importing a package in PyCharm (for Windows)

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import, python-packaging

Could anyone:

- write a very short example of a Python package created in PyCharm (under Windows)
- then import it into a script/module
- and finally run it from PyCharm Terminal?

Comment: PLEASE NOTE:  **I've done more than 10 hours of research here, on IntelliJ and on Google** and I can't arrive to this simple sample project. Mine won't work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

pycharm imports module from the root folder (e.g. src/module) with folders being seperated by dots `import src.module`

pycharm will run any code by selecting the file and doing `ctrl` + `shift` + `f10`

modules in python are folders with a `__init__.py` which imports all methods/classes/variable into them

Comment: To be more specific, [my issue is closest to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57760296/can-not-import-package-created-in-pycharm). But it's an abnormal hard-coded workaround for such a basic import task.

Comment: @SolidT. could you please edit you question to have a picture of your file structure

Comment: I am not allowed to post answers for now. I give up on Stack.
Thus, I am not enabled to post the answer I have consistently worked on, including the excellent communication with JetBrains Support Team.